# How to create text file using VBA for Excel for MacOS

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a file and save text into it. I tried below code but when I am using **write #1**, script will just replace existing text with the new text. I tried **write #0** but no luck. Any suggestions.

```
Sub TestResultFile(output As String)
  Dim myFile As String
  myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "TestResults.txt"
  Debug.Print myFile
  Open myFile For Output As #1
  Write #1, output
  Close #1
End Sub
```

Update:

Answer by Lakshmi helped me solve this issue.

Comment: If you look it up in *The Programmers Guide to Visual Basic* it says *Visual Basic allows you to process drives, folders, and files in two different ways: through traditional methods such as the Open statement, Write#, and so forth, and through a new set of tools, the File System Object (FSO) object model*.

Comment: @Noodles I am not able to use File System Object (FSO) because FSO if for Excel for Windows. Can you please confirm?

Comment: Try `Open myFile For Append As #1`

Comment: @xmojmr output is my string variable without that what you are trying to add in `Open myFile For Append As #1`

Comment: @meMadhav I mean try to use different file open mode. Instead of `For Output` use `For Append`. Then write your `output` string to the file and it should not replace existing text

Comment: @xmojmr Thank you man. For Append resolved my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

User **Append** to add text to new line.

try below code-

```
Sub TestResultFile(output As String)
  Dim myFile As String
  myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "TestResults.txt"
  Debug.Print myFile
  Open myFile For Append As #1
  Write #1, output
  Close #1
End Sub
```